# foreach loop executing one by one in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I have a view in which I have to execute foreach loops. The problem is that I want to get one input from first foreach then get the other input from the second foreach. I have an outer for loop which will execute until all the foreach is exhausted.

```
@for($i=0;$i<=$n;$i++)
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{$i}}</th>

        @foreach($Names as $Name)&&
            <td>{{$Name}}</td>
        @endforeach

        @foreach($users as $user)
            <td>{{$user}}</td>
        @endforeach
@endfor
```

Comment: So, put the second foreach inside the first?

Comment: Do you mean to print all the names and all the users in only one row with a bunch of columns?

Comment: Do the inner loops have the  same number of iterations?

Comment: @ Jon String: that will not work since it will multiply the number of iterations.

Comment: @Magnus: i want it as         1    name1     user1     then in the next row as     2.    name2   user2   and so on..

Comment: @Jnana : yes same number of iterations...

Comment: Ok. Looking at the code you've presented, they will all be listed in one single row. And you probably should format your arrays before the loop. Are you fetching the names and users from a database? Then just join the tables upon fetching to get one good looking array to iterate through

Comment: @Jijo FYI you forgot to close the <tr> element.

Comment: @  Francesco Casula :yes i put <tr> still not happening.

Comment: do we know if these are 0 indexed ? i suppose not

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
@foreach($Names as $key => $val)&&
    <td> {{$val}}</td>
    <td> {{$users[$key]}}  </td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: no its not happening.. i want my out put as: 1 name1 user1  then in the next <tr> as 2. name2 user2

Comment: then u have to open ans close `<tr>` inside loop

Answer (score 0):

Your making a mistake with your structure here. You should have the Users and there names and username in one variable so you can foreach this result.

```
@foreach($users as $user)
<tr>
<td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
<td>{{ $user->user }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

If you want to add numbers to the list just add a counter with css or php if thats your way.

```
<?php $i=1; ?>    
@foreach($users as $user)
        <tr>
<td>{{ $i }}
        <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->user }}</td>
        </tr>
<?php $i++; ?>
        @endforeach
```

Comment: Users and there names and username in not one variable

Answer (score 0):

thanks for trying guys. I got the answer...

```
@foreach($Names as $Name)
            <tr>

                    <th scope="row">{{$i++}}</th>
                    {{--@foreach(@Names as $Name)--}}
                    <th> {{$Name}}</th>

                    @foreach($users as $user )

                    <td> {!! Form::text($users.$i,null, array('class' => 'form-control','id'=>$i)) !!} </td>

                        @endforeach

               </tr>

            @endforeach
```

The catch was that for loop and foreach required the same number of iterations. So we can simply eliminate for loop.